# Experimenting boot issues

Tags: grub2

Hi and thanks for your time

I turn on my PC and i get this message in the screen

```
"GNU GRUB 0.97 Minimal bash-like line editing..."
```

From an Ubuntu live CD i installed boot-repair utility, i tried recommended repair without success, then i created a boot info summary in order to share it and get some help. The log is in this URL http://paste.ubuntu.com/10858749/.

Thanks from now for any suggestion.

Comment: The log says that boot-repair didn't do anything because it couldn't find any OS. Try other options.

Comment: how can i target the proper hard drive in boot-repair?

Comment: It looks at all that are attached.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to reinstall grub, assuming that it is the first hard drive in your system, from a terminal on the LiveCD, type in

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

assuming that /dev/sda is your first hard drive in your system.

Then type in

```
sudo update-grub
```

to update a new grub file for the system.

Comment: To find out your hard drives, the quickest way I have found is to type in `sudo fdisk -l` from a terminal window, then it will say something like `Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes` as the very first line.

Comment: Hi terrance

I just try sudo fdisk -l and get /dev/sda and /dev/sdb

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes

But when i try sudo grub-install /dev/sda

I get

grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.

Any idea?

Comment: Might need to download one of the installer ISOs and put it on a USB drive.  Boot it up as the Try Ubuntu setting, that way it will allow it.  I am thinking that your LiveCD might be missing that directory.